# Custom skin for custom control via Delphi VCL Styles API?

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

I'd like to use Delphi's built-in Styles API to apply custom skins to my own visual controls.

Delphi's Style Designer allows adding custom style images and objects. But how do I make use of them inside a custom control?

`GetElementDetails` only excepts the predefined element types (button, checkbox, etc.) and `StyleServices` doesn't seem to provide access to custom style objects otherwise.

Is there a way?

Comment: Have you tryed to use another visual components, like [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com) or [JediProject](http://www.delphi-jedi.org)? They offer a bunch of components then you can use to personalize styles and objects by simple drag and drop configurations.

Comment: As far as I have seen, all VCL component packs out there either exclusively use the standard VCL styles elements or implement their own style system. I wish to use the native styles API, if at all possible.